# How to iterate through all website address in this world?

Tags: networking, dns, web-crawler

There are lots of sites use virtual host. When writing a crawler, even iterate through all IPs, I cannot get all sites.

If a ip is bound to several host names, such as `a.test.com`, `b.a.test.com`. Will the reverse dns lookup return all the subdomain names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Reverse lookup tells you whatever the people controlling the reverse zone wants. There is, by design, no way to find all existing domain names.

Comment: Regardless of that the people controlling the reverse zone want, reverse DNS lookups support returning only one name per IP query. There isn't a way to return a list of names.

Comment: That is incorrect. There is no technical problem with having multiple PTR RRs for a particular name. There is a general recommendation not to do that, since some programs aren't able to handle it, but that's it.